# How to modify capturing group with n element inside

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a var who can contains 1 to n value :

```
var v = `"type":"List("one","two","n")","allowNull":false,"defaultValue":"null"`
```

i need to parse it with regular expression for modify all list element for looking like this :

```
"type":"List('one element','two element','n element')","allowNull":false,"defaultValue":"null"
```

I have done this regular expression : (List()((")([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(")(,?)){1,}())

But i don't know how to loop inside my 4 th capturing group.

Anyone know how to do it ?

updated regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/0TnKur/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/0TnKur/3)** .

**updated**

Try this :

1. Fist match the list using this regex`/(List\()(.*)(\))/g`
2. Second replace with element string using this regex `(")(\w+)(")`
3. Finaly replace with `changed string` from `old string` using this
   `v.replace( list, matched)`function

```js
var v =`"type":"List("one","two","n")","allowNull":false,"defaultValue":"null"`
 var list = v.match(/(List\()(.*)(\))/g);
var matched= list[0].replace(/(")(\w+)(")/g, "\'$2 element\'");
var res =v.replace( list, matched)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: @JoffreyHernandez  see the updated answer. its ok.Input and output both are dual quotes.

Comment: see the console,log `element` string added with  list

Comment: @prasad Looks like he needs to replace double quotes with single quotes inside List() only

Comment: @JoffreyHernandez i was forget the single quotes inside the `list()`.see the updated answer is it ok